# Change default DateTime culture invariant on application level in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

> My current DateTime DataType culture is MM/dd/yyyy. I want to change
>   it to dd/MM/yyyy on application level.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your `Program.cs` file as below:

```
public class Program
    {
                public static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
                    culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                    culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss tt";
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                }
     }
```

Check anywhere in your application

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
```

It will return date value in your specified format in `Program.cs`